# How to set QStyleOptionButton like a checkbox with custom icons

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qstyleditemdelegate, qicon

I have a custom `Delegate` class which inherits from `QStyledItemDelegate`. In its `paint()` event, I would like to add `QStyleOptionButton` which should be checkable. Is it possible?

For example, it denotes visibility property with an icon of eye; and when the button is pressed, the eye icon turns into closed-eye icon.

Inside the `paint()` method, this is my current code to create the button:

```
QStyleOptionButton buttonVis;
buttonVis.rect = getButtonVisibilityRect();
buttonVis.iconSize = QSize(sizeX, sizeY);
buttonVis.icon = icon;
buttonVis.state = QStyle::State_Enabled;
buttonVis.features = QStyleOptionButton::None;

QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, &buttonVis, painter);
```

The icon that I load to the `buttonVis` is created by:

```
QIcon icon;
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/control-visibility.svg"), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);
icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/control-visibilityNo.svg"), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
```

For the moment when I run my program, the button has an icon with closed eye. Is there a command to control which icon is displayed? If my initial layout is not possible to implement, what is the right direction to go?

**EDIT**: I found out how to select which icon to use in order to simulate the checkbox look. Instead if line `buttonVis.state = QStyle::State_Enabled;` there should be:

```
if (/* current item checkbox checked? */)
    buttonVis.state = QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_On;
else
    buttonVis.state = QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_Off;
```

The problem now is to figure out what is that condition or how to set it up from the `editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)`. The problem is that I cannot really change `option` by myself since it is constant reference. Any ideas how to do it, or how to get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out how to set up certain flag and then test for it and see if the button changed an icon.

So, for the icon change, as I mentioned on the edit of my question, I have to use something like:

```
buttonVis.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
buttonVis.state |= isChanged? QStyle::State_Off : QStyle::State_On;
```

So it comes down on how to set up `isChanged` flag. And it can be done within `editorEvent()` method of the delegate:

```
bool Delegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const StyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if (/* event is release and it is over the button area*/)
    {
        bool value = index.data(Qt::UserRole).toBool();
        // this is how we setup the condition flag
        model->setData(index, !value, Qt::UserRole);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now to use the setup flag, we do it in the `paint()` event right before we set up `buttonVis.state`:

```
bool isChanged = index.data(Qt::UserRole).toBool();
```

By adding these steps my `QStyleOptionButton` is now behaving like a checkbox, but it changes icons as states.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
QStyleOptionButton option;
option.initFrom(this);
...
QStylePainter p(this);
if (option.state.testFlag(QStyle::State_Sunken)) {
    p.drawPixmap(this->rect(), QPixmap(":/control-visibility"));
} else {
    p.drawPixmap(this->rect(), QPixmap(":/control-visibilityNo"));
}
```

Be careful with SVG file, try first with PNG.

> QStyle::State_Sunken   0x00000004   Used to indicate if the widget is
>   sunken or pressed.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I found how to switch the icons: `buttonVis.state = QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_Off;` or `buttonVis.state = QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_On;`. I tried your proposed condition `option.state.testFlag(QStyle::State_Sunken)`, but it does not seem to do the trick. It does not seem this flag is set whenever I click on my button, and I am not sure how to force it to switch the states automatically. In delegate's `editorEvent` I can check when I press on the button, however, I cannot change the `option` since it is passed as `const &`.